# Sorting a string based upon value in square bracket

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string eg:

```
[01:07]bbbbbbb[00:48]aaaaaa[01:36]ccccccccc[03:45]gggggggg[03:31]fffffff[01:54]ddddddddd[02:09]eeeeeee[03:59]hhhhhhhh
```

this needs to be Sorted as

```
[00:48]aaaaaa[01:07]bbbbbbb[01:36]ccccccccc[01:54]ddddddddd[02:09]eeeeeee[03:31]fffffff[03:45]gggggggg[03:59]hhhhhhhh
```

which is based upon the string inside the square bracket.
how can i do this in java?

Comment: When you say "aligned", you mean "sorted", right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Suggested algorithm

You could simply:

1. **split** your `String` on each new *timestamp*, then
2. **sort** the resulting array and finally
3. **concatenate** its ordered content.

### Actual code sample

Using the `Stream` library introduced in **Java 8**, it can be done in within a single expression:

```
final String sorted = Arrays.asList(input.split("(?=\\[)")).stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

### Original answer pre-Java 8

```
final String input = "[01:07]bbbbbbb[00:48]aaaaaa[01:36]ccccccccc[03:45]gggggggg[03:31]fffffff[01:54]ddddddddd[02:09]eeeeeee[03:59]hhhhhhhh";
final String entries[] = input.split("(?=\\[)");
Arrays.sort(entries);

String res = "";
for (final String entry : entries) {
    res += entry;
}

System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
[00:48]aaaaaa[01:07]bbbbbbb[01:36]ccccccccc[01:54]ddddddddd[02:09]eeeeeee[03:31]fffffff[03:45]gggggggg[03:59]hhhhhhhh
```

### Follow-up question in the comments section

> why do I do `input.split("(?=\\[)")`?

`String#split` works with a *Regular Expression* but `[` (and `]`) are not standard characters, "regex-wise". So, they need to be **escaped** — using `\[` (and `\]`).

However, in a *Java* `String`, `\` is not a standard character either, and needs to be **escaped as well**.

See [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21816839/2427596) for more details.

Comment: @ccjmne can you please explain input.split("\\["), I am aware of the split method but never seen this kind of splitting. Lil bit elaboration would be really appreciated.

Comment: @kapilchhattani Sure, you're right, I should/could have explained this. I just added that explanation to my answer. Thank you for pointing that out!