# Unclosed Character Class Error?

Tags: java, regex, split

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 3
], [
   ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2493)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2030)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2313)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2355)
    at testJunior2013.J2.main(J2.java:31)
```

This is the area of the code that is causing the issues.

```
String[][] split = new String[1][rows];

split[0] = (Arrays.deepToString(array2d)).split("], ["); //split at the end of an array row
```

What does this error mean and what needs to be done to fix the code above?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

## TL;DR

You want:

```java
.split("\\], \\[")`
```

**Escape** each square bracket **twice** — once for each context in which you need to strip them from their special meaning: within a [*Regular Expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) first, and within a [*Java String*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) secondly.

Consider using [`Pattern#quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) when you need your **entire pattern** to be interpreted **literally**.

---

## Explanation

[`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) works with a [*Regular Expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) but `[` and `]` are not standard characters, regex-wise: they have a special meaning in that context.

In order to **strip them from their special meaning** and simply *match actual square brackets*, they need to be **escaped**, which is done by preceding each with a **backslash** — that is, using `\[` and `\]`.

However, in a [*Java String*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html), `\` is not a standard character either, and needs to be **escaped as well**.

Thus, just to split on `[`, the *String* used is `"\\["` and you are trying to obtain:

```java
.split("\\], \\[")
```

---

### A sensible alternative

However, in this case, you're not just semantically *escaping a few specific characters in a Regular Expression*, but actually wishing that **your entire pattern be interpreted literally**: there's a method to do just that

[`Pattern#quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) is used to signify that the:

> Metacharacters [...] in your pattern will be given no special meaning.

(from the Javadoc linked above)

I recommend, in this case, that you use the following, more sensible and readable:

```java
.split(Pattern.quote("], ["))
```

Comment: This is just the answer i was looking for, thank you. In what cases should I use `Pattern.quote` instead of the standard `.split("\\], [\\")`?

Comment: You "should" always use `Pattern.quote`, because it's equivalent to escaping the regex string yourself... but using this, you're sure that you won't forget anything and besides that, it's more readable, in my opinion :)

Answer (score 6):

Split receives a regex and [, ] characters have meaning in regex, so you should escape them with `\\[` and `\\]`.

The way you are currently doing it, the parser finds a ] without a preceding [ so it throws that error.

Answer (score 2):

String.split() takes a *regular expression*, not a normal string as an argument. In a regular expression, ] and [ are special characters, which need to be preceded by backslashes to be taken literally. Use `.split("\\], \\[")`. (the double backslashes tell Java to interpret the string as "\], \[").

Answer (score 1):

```
  .split("], [")
             ^---start of char class
                  end----?
```

Change it to

```
.split("], \[")
           ^---escape the [
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate?

Comment: It's good to try a solution before submitting it on SO ;) Keep in mind that this question is about Java

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it

```
 String stringToSplit = "8579.0,753.34,796.94,\"[784.2389999999999,784.34]\",\"[-4.335912230999999, -4.3603307895,4.0407909059, 4.08669583455]\",[],[],[],0.1744,14.4,3.5527136788e-15,0.330667850653,0.225286999939,Near_Crash";
 String [] arraySplitted = stringToSplit.replaceAll("\"","").replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("\\]","").trim().split(",");
```