# Unclosed character class near index 525

Tags: java, regex, patternsyntaxexception

I'm a new programmer in general, so forgive me if this issue is a fair bit base.

This program's goal is a simple calculation of "optimal body weight," and continually throws an exception during runtime over the a and b string comparisons in Line 35. I've attempted removing the logic operators and that still does not seem to be the issue. Where am I wrong?

```
import java.util.*;

public class WeightCalc {

  //Initialize variables
  static int feet = 0, inches = 0, totalWeight = 0;
  static boolean isMale;

  public static void optimalWeight(){
    // Calculate optimal weight
    if (isMale == true){
      if (feet >= 5){
        totalWeight = 106 + 6*(inches);
      } else{
        System.out.print("Error, you're a midget.");
      }
    }
    if (isMale == false){  
      if (feet >= 5){
        totalWeight = 100 + 5*(inches);
      } else{
        System.out.print("Error, you're a midget.");
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

    String a = "Male", b = "male";

    // Initialize kboard Scanner
    Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Ask for gender and assign isMale
    System.out.println("What is your gender? ");
    String gender = kboard.nextLine();
    if (gender.equals(a) || gender.equals(b)){
      isMale = true;
    }else {
      isMale = false;
    }

    // Ask for height, first feet, then inches
    System.out.println("What is your height in regards to feet? ");
    kboard.nextInt(feet);
    System.out.println("What is your remaining h eight in inches? ");
    kboard.nextInt(inches);

    //Call optimalWeight method and run
    optimalWeight();

    // Print the output
    System.out.println("Your optimal weight should be " + totalWeight + ".");

    // Set isMale opposite to what it was before and calculate opposite sex's potential weight
    isMale = !isMale;
    optimalWeight();

    // Print the output of the second run
    System.out.println("If you were of the opposite sex, your weight would be " + totalWeight + ".");

    // Close the Scanner variable
    kboard.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Which is line 35? `if (gender.equals(a) || gender.equals(b)){`? And what is the exception?

Comment: Don't compare booleans using `a == true` or `a == false`. Just use `a` or `!a`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816788/unclosed-character-class-error

Comment: Try initializing a and b on two separate lines. `String a = "Male"; String b = "male";`

Comment: and why test for two different strings? Why not just have `male` and to a `toLower()` on the input string? Otherwise you'll simply have `mAlE` become isMale = false

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, that'd be the line. The exception is as follows: <code> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 525
</code>

Comment: Check your line number again, because there is **no** regex processing in the line `if (gender.equals(a) || gender.equals(b))`. More likely, it's in the `kboard.nextInt(feet)` line, which should be `feet = kboard.nextInt()`.

Comment: I think this is actually a bug in OpenJDK - not so much the behaviour, but the cryptic error. It seems like the [`setRadix`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.setRadix%28int%29) method could have a check for `radix < 2`. But then, it's probably not the common a problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` defines that it will throw `NumberFormatException` for a bad radix value, and `nextInt(int radix)` defines that it will call `parseInt()`, so they were probably relying on its validation, not realizing that the regex is going bad for a `0` radix *before* it gets to call `parseInt()`.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report.

Comment: This issue has been accepted by Oracle as [bug JDK-8166261](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8166261).

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
kboard.nextInt(feet);
```

should be

```
feet = kboard.nextInt();
```

When you provide an int parameter to `Scanner.nextInt`, it is considered the radix of the number you're going to enter. `feet`'s value is zero, and you can't really have a radix zero number, hence the error.

---

Note that the error [doesn't occur on the line you claim](http://ideone.com/w331WQ):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 525
(([-+]?(((((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})++)|([\p{javaDigit}&&[^0]]((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?(\,((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit}))+)))))|(((((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})++)|([\p{javaDigit}&&[^0]]((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?(\,((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit}))+)))|(\Q-\E((((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})++)|([\p{javaDigit}&&[^0]]((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})?(\,((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[]|\p{javaDigit}))+)))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2548)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2063)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2905)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2905)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2905)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2905)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2905)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2905)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.util.Scanner$1.create(Scanner.java:367)
    at java.util.Scanner$1.create(Scanner.java:365)
    at sun.misc.LRUCache.forName(LRUCache.java:72)
    at java.util.Scanner.integerPattern(Scanner.java:443)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at WeightCalc.main(Main.java:45)
```

The penultimate line here:

```
java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
```

shows that it's in `Scanner.nextInt`.

Comment: Wouldn't the important line be `WeightCalc.main(Main.java:45)`, indicating that it is line **45** that's the culprit?

Comment: @Andreas well, sure, but you can see that it's a problem with the call to `nextInt` without looking at the line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the wrong `Scanner.readInt`. You want to call the empty args one that returns an `int`.

The one you calling takes an `int` as an input that's supposed to be the number base (i.e. the number is in octal or binary, etc). Since `feet` and `inches` are both initialized to 0, it attempts to read an `int` in base 0, which is impossible.

What you want is something more like:

```
// Ask for height, first feet, then inches 
System.out.println("What is your height in regards to feet? ");
feet = kboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("What is your remaining h eight in inches? ");
inches = kboard.nextInt();
```