# Unclosed character class while replacing string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove a string at the beginning of another.

Example:

| Begin | Removed | Final |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "\n123 : other" | **Yes** | other |
| "123 : other" | No | **Error** |
| "\n4 : smth" | **Yes** | smth |
| "123 : a" | No | **Error** |

Thanks to [Regexr](https://regexr.com/), I made this regex:

```
/[\\][n](?:[0-9]*)[ ][:]/g
```

I tried to use it in Java. With `string.matches()` I don't have any error. But, with `string.replaceFirst`, I have this error :

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 24
/[\][n](?:[0-9]*)[ ][:]/g
                        ^
```

What I tried else ?

- Remove `/` at begin and `/g` at end.
- Add `(pattern)` (such as visible in regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41328567/10952503))
- Multiple others quick way, but I the error is always at the last char of my regex

My full code:

```
String str = "\n512 : something"; // I init my string
if(str.matches("/[\\][n](?:[0-9]*)[ ][:]/g"))
   str = str.replaceFirst("/[\\][n](?:[0-9]*)[ ][:]/g", "");
```

How can I fix it ? How can I solve my regex pattern ?

Comment: The `\n` in `"\n"` is a newline, not a backslash and `n`. So, it should be `str = str.replaceFirst("\n[0-9]+\\s+:\\s*", "")`. Do not use `str.matches`. Using `g` (`g`lobal flag to match all occurrences) with `.replaceFirst` is not only invalid, it is not logical.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I don't have error now, but it didn't find something

Comment: See https://ideone.com/iMAFJS, what did you mean by "it didn't find something"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't change the string. But I found the issue, when I copy paste, I made a typo error. So yes, your regex works fine thanks ! Can you make an answer for this ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
.replaceFirst("\n[0-9]+\\s+:\\s*", "")
```

The regex matches

- `\n` - a newline char (you have a newline in the string, not a backslash and `n`)
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/iMAFJS):

```java
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("\n123 : other", "123 : other", "\n4 : smth", "123 : a");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println("\"" + str.replaceFirst("\n[0-9]+\\s+:\\s*", "") + "\"");
```

Output:

```
"other"
"123 : other"
"smth"
"123 : a"
```